# Powershell - Get content from text file before/after a new line

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file that contains the following data:

```
A1
A2
A3
A5
A6

B1 = 4
B2 = 3
B3 = 3
B4 = 5

C1 = 6
C2 = 4
C3 = 2
```

Now, I want to extract the data from text file and store into variable each block / before the new line, how can I do this in powershell? I tried lots of ways from google but can't seem to find solution. Please help, I'm new in powershell. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tell us more about what you tried, what errors you faced and what code you already have. We need more information to give you a good answer.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what your trying to do, wouldn't it make more sense to split each item on `=` and put them in a hashtable? Then you don't need to keep track of a million variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions and help.
This now resolved.

Above I have 3 queries and their result is saved to a text file, I placed * in between as an indicator. This maybe a bad practice, but I hope to improve my code soon.

First line is to get the content -Raw, to retrieve data as one.
Second line is to split each data by an asterisk and save each to a different variable, namely below.
Third and Fourth line is to split the block of data line by line, this is now treated as an array.
5th and 6th line, is to convert the array of string to a hash table key/value pair.

```
$content = Get-Content $Attachment -Raw
$Monitor,$ServerName, $Hourly = $content | foreach split '*'
$ServerName = $ServerName -split '\r?\n'
$Monitor = $Monitor -split '\r?\n'

$Monitor= ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $Monitor
$Hourly = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $Hourly
```

Answer (score 6):

You should probably include more information in your question such as what specifically you've tried already. You also don't say if you want the block boundary to be basted of A changing to B or the double newline? and you want to access each block as a single object (a string extending multiple newlines?). If the above assumptions are correct, this would do the trick:

```
$var = (Get-Content test.txt -Raw) -split "`r`n`r`n"

$var[0]
$var[1]
$var[2]
```

This works if the file is in Windows EOL format (\R \N) and has a double space between the blocks. Get-content reads every line to an array by default, so -Raw gives us a giant string to work with ourselves.

Comment: you likely otta change `basted` to `based`. i'm still giggling over the visual ... [*grin*] other than that, nice answer!